# android のbluetoothシャッターボタンの仕組み

Tags: android, bluetooth

bluetoothのシャッターボタンについて。
androidでbluetoothシャッターボタンを使う時、音量downが、シャッターボタンで動作して、カメラ動作となると思います。
これってbluetoothハード側で、どのようなものか定義されているわけですよね？
もしこれを音量upや、電源に変えたい場合どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14213141454

Comment: マルチポストでだめなんですか。。そこらへんのマナーわからなくて、すみません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetoothの仕様というよりも、Android端末側でのハード的な制限でシャッターボタンが無い場合に
音量ボタンをシャッター代わりにする機能があり(端末自体の設定、またはカメラアプリの設定)、
これに合わせてBluetoothのシャッターボタンも実装されているんじゃないかと思います。

「Bluetoothのシャッターボタンがうまく動作しない場合には、端末またはアプリの設定で音量ボタンをシャッターに割り当ててみてください」という注意書きがほとんどです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そこらへんの仕組みを知りたくて。僕は、bluetoothのボタンをいじりたいのですが、それはandroid側とbluetooth側で定義されているだろうと思っています。そこらへんを教えてほしいです。